# Removing element from std::vector

Tags: c++, std

I would like to remove an element from a std::vector v using

```
v.erase( std::remove_if( std::begin(v), std::end(v), pred), std::end(v) );
```

I know that the removable element (if exist) it must be between index1 and index2. Is there any way to use this information with remove_if?

Comment: Yes, a lambda fits in nicely.

Comment: Can you give more details how...?

Comment: Is your question about what pred should be, or how to get remove_if to only search the region between index1 and index2?

Comment: Oh, good point. I read the question wrong.

Comment: I do not know how to get remove_if to only search the region between index1 and index2. It will return an iterator either to index2 or index2-1. In the last case do I have to swap index2 with last element of v? Or is a simpler way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If there is just one element to removed it seems the approch to go is to use `std::find_if()` rather than `std::remove_if()` and locate the object in the specific range:

```
auto it = std::find_if(v.begin() + index1, v.begin() + index2, pred);
if (it != v.begin() + index2) {
    v.erase(it);
}
```

If there are potentially more elements you could use

```
v.erase(std::remove_if(v.begin() + index1, v.begin() + index2, pred), v.begin() + index2);
```

You can use `v.erase()` to remove elements from an internal range.

Answer (score 0):

This will only search between index1 and index2, NOT including either index. It's up to you to make sure the range is still valid.

```
v.erase( std::remove_if( std::begin(v) + index1 + 1, std::begin(v) + index2, pred), v.begin() + index2);
```

Comment: Will this not remove everything from v after index2?

Comment: @robogos I made an amendment.

Answer (score 0):

```
v.erase( std::remove_if( std::begin(v) + index1, std::begin(v) + index2, pred), std::begin(v) + index2 );
```